# Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I couldn't see any thing.Here is my ManagedBean;

```
public class AralikKontrolEvent {

private String sayi;
private String mesaj="";

public String getMesaj() {
    return mesaj;
}

public void setMesaj(String mesaj) {
    this.mesaj = mesaj;
}

public String getSayi() {
    return sayi;
}

public void setSayi(String sayi) {
    this.sayi = sayi;
}

public void SayiKontrolEt(ActionEvent event){

    int a = Integer.parseInt(sayi);
    if(event.getComponent().getId().equals("gonder")){
        if(a>10){
            mesaj+="Sayı büyük";
        }else{
            mesaj+="Sayı küçük";
        }
    }

}
```

I called **SayiKontrolEt** method like below;

```
< h : commandButton value="Gönder" id="gonder" action="#{ake.SayiKontrolEt}"/>
```

But I get this error.I have looked lots of examples about jsf event.Everybody calls like I have called the method.What is the wrong which I haven't seen?

Comment: Instead of `action="#{ake.SayiKontrolEt}"`, try `actionListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Remove ActionEvent from the method
2. Or change action to actionListener

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ActionEvent argument from the method.

Comment: I want to use event handler.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't looking at method body.

Comment: ... but you can do that by binding attribute in the commandButton, that will reference jsf UIButton component in the @Named bean.